# Highmaps - map not rendering

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I've have had some problems with the highmaps library since a while back. I got reports from users that a map displaying statistics was not rendering sometimes.

When looking at the problem, I noticed that the map rendered quite inconsistently, sometimes perfect, but quite often - not at all.

When consulting the documentation at [highcharts docs](http://video.arkena.com/play2/embed/player?accountId=123516&mediaId=37abf85e-00090006-00448f9f&configId=default&pageStyling=adaptive&autoplay=true&repeat=true&sharing=true) I realised that the example on jsfiddle suffers from the exact same problem. Sometimes the map simply does not render. I made a screen recording to show the problem.

This problem occurs in chrome and ff, I have not tried other browsers.

This is my code for the map, it's a part of a Angular app.

```
  function createChart() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Map({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'mapContainer'
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
        floating: false,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
      },
      colorAxis: {
        maxColor: '#7b9b00',
        minColor: '#d7e241',
        type: 'linear',
        allowDecimals: false,
        marker: {
          color: 'black'
        },
        minPadding: 0.005
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br>' +
            'Asset Hits: ' + this.point.options.hits + '<br>' +
            'Total Volume: ' + this.point.options.volume + '<br>';
        },
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        name: 'countries',
        showInLegend: false,
        borderWidth: 0.2,
        states: {
          hover: {
            borderWidth: 1
          }
        }
      }]
    });
  }

  scope.$on('geoData', function(event, data) {
    var validData = function (data) {
      var equal = _.isEqual(data, cachedData);
      if (!equal && data.length > 1) {
        return data;
      }
        };

        if (validData) {
          if (!chart) {
            createChart();
          }
          updateSeries(data);
        }
        cachedData = data;
      }, true);

      function updateSeries(data) {
        if (chart !== undefined) {
          if (chart.series.length > 1) {
            chart.series[1].remove();
          }
        }
        chart.addSeries({
          data: data,
          title: 'Performance by Country',
          mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
          joinBy: ['hc-key', 'countryiso'],
          name: 'countries',
          borderWidth: 0.2,
          borderColor: 'black',
          states: {
            hover: {
              borderWidth: 1,
              color: '#7b9b00'
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Video displaying the issue: 
[Link to video](http://video.arkena.com/play2/embed/player?accountId=123516&mediaId=37abf85e-00090006-00448f9f&configId=default&pageStyling=adaptive&autoplay=true&repeat=true&sharing=true)

Comment: If it happens also on jsfiddle, then I suggest to report it on the github as a bug https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues However, it might be hard to debug without the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @morganfree I updated the bug report on github!